# The design form in Visual Studio 2019 looks different than the one during running

Tags: visual-studio, winforms, windows-forms-designer

I am using VB.NET under Visual Studio 2019.
The form I am seeing when designing it looks different than the one used when running:

[image: Sample screenshot]

I changed "Enable XP visual styles", but that affects the look only at the runtime.
Do you have any idea on how to make the design form looking identical to the one at running time?

Comment: You cannot change it. The form which is hosted in designer is not a top-level form and the top-level window theme will not apply on it. (It may be a bug in windows API or it may be by design, but it doesn't have anything to do with Visual Studio, Windows Forms .NET or your visual style settings.)

Comment: @RezaAghaei, thank you for your answer.